# How can I link an edit page to my detail page in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

So I am trying to link the template where I can edit a post like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:post_update' pk=post.pk %}">Edit</a>
```

But is giving me this error:

```
Reverse for 'eintrag_update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 63L}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'gaestebuch/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/edit/$']
```

But I can get access to the template like this without an error: /blog/(id)/edit

Every other link on this template is working, for example I have a link just next to it like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:delete_post' pk=post.pk %}">Delete</a>
```

Which works perfectly fine.

This is my view:

```
def post_update(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance = instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "blog/write.html", context)
```

This is my url:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_update, name='post_update'),
```

And this is my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
```

I would be really glad if someone could help me!

Comment: The danger of translating `eintrag` to `post` is that you might hide the error! In this case I think I've spotted the problem anyway.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I tried to make it easier to understand. And thanks very much again for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword arguments in the url patterns must match the keyword arguments in the url tag.

You are using the keyword argument `pk`

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:post_update' pk=post.pk %}">Edit</a>
```

So you should use `pk` in your url pattern as well. At the moment you are using `id`.

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_update, name='post_update'),
```

That means you probably have to update your view as well, for example:

```
def post_update(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    ...
```

You could leave the view and url pattern as they are, and change the url tag to use `id` instead. However, I recommend using `pk`, because that's what Django uses in class based views.

Another option is to use args instead of kwargs in the url tag.

```
{% url 'blog:post_update' post.pk %}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, again for your help!